# java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, sql, database

```
private void jbx_ItemPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                      
       try{
          conn=ShopDb.database();
          con2=ShopDb.database();
        String cth_item=(String) jbx_Item.getSelectedItem();
       comboUpdate(cth_item);

      String quary2="select qunine from stock where itemID = ? ";

     stm2=con2.prepareStatement(quary2);
     stm2.setString(1,cth_item);
     res2=stm2.executeQuery(); 
    if(res2.next()){
  Double fil2= res.getDouble("quninew");

   String valu = Double.toString(fil2);
   txtBill_availailty.setText(valu);
    }


   }catch(SQLException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
   }



}
```

Comment: my problem is thisi m geting this when i choose the combo box   java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Comment: You're sure it's this statement that is causing the problem? Does he stacktrace point to these lines?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do

```
Double fil2= res.getDouble("qunine");
```

Instead of

```
Double fil2= res.getDouble("quninew");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching qunine and retrieving quninew from resultset. Fix it first and check issue is still there or not or else provide the stacktrace.